# WPF SelectionChanged event do the action before tab change

Tags: c#, wpf

i have SelectionChanged event in my WPF aplication. i want that when the tab is change to do some action but first i want the tab to visualy change **before** the action starts. i am using background worker to do the job. my code is:

```
    private void Tab_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (tab1.IsSelected)
        {
            //this line is not working
            tabcontrol.SelectedIndex = 1;
            wNetTest = new BackgroundWorker();
            wNetTest.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
            wNetTest.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            wNetTest.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            wNetTest.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            wNetTest.RunWorkerAsync();

        }
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //do the job
    }
```

Comment: the issue is that when i chane the tab the tab does not change until the action is done. i want the tab to change before the action in DoWork is started.

Comment: Then why have you started a new thread in Backgroundworker?

Comment: i want to add progress bar to the main thread.i dont want the main job to stuck the main thread.

Comment: if you are sure that the code you are about to execute only may occur when user sees the view and changes tabs using mouse or keyboard then use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke and postpone the action to dispatcher not being in use means priority is set to background ensuring all drawings are done and dispatcher is ready to proceed your action

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your code is running synchronously. Therefore, every line of your `Tab_SelectionChanged` event handler will run *before* you will see the `TabItem` change. To fix this problem, you just need to run your long running process asynchronously. One of the simplest ways to do that is this:

```
private void Tab_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (tab1.IsSelected)
    {
        //this line is not working
        tabcontrol.SelectedIndex = 1;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LongRunningMethod(parameter));

    }
}

private void LongRunningMethod(object parameter)
{
    // perform long running process here
}
```

The `parameter` input parameter is optional... just remove it if you don't need it.